# Did Derren Brown use subliminal messages in this trick?

Tags: mind-control

The trick I'm talking about is on this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZS85ipnQzw

It is approximately 7 minutes long. In this, he shows two tricks, purportedly he achieves them using subliminal messages.

In the first trick, he asks a volunteer to select a card, which look the same(white background), I don't exactly know what he means by subliminal in this 1st trick, because I think the volunteer is guided to select two cards by him by snapping his fingers over the cards he wants her to choose. When she selects one of the card(forced by him by snapping), he asks if she'd like to change, and she changes her selection to a different(on which also he snapped), at the end of the trick it is revealed that the card she chooses the second time has the words "pick me" in invisible ultraviolet color and she chose it because of this message. This card also has the word lose written on it's underside.

In the 2nd trick, he claims to use similar subliminal message, he asks 20 stooges to come on stage, all of them wear similar colored green t-shirt with a whitish rectangular box on the front of the t-shirt over their belly. He asks the same volunteer to select one of them, the volunteer selects the one with the word lose on their back, Derren Brown explains he made this stooge's rectangular box more appealing subliminally.

I presently suspect I'm being shown subliminal messages on my computer, these are of 3 types:

1. Messages shown for short duration
2. Messages whose color is slightly varied to blend with the background
3. Messages whose opacity is changed to blend with the background

Two of these are slightly similar to the one in Derren Brown's trick. I want know if there are studies which show that these kind of subliminal messages are effective?

Comment: A story in *The Telegraph* in 2009 says: [Subliminal advertising really does work, claim scientists](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/6232801/Subliminal-advertising-really-does-work-claim-scientists.html) and describes a [study published](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxuaWxsaWxhdmllfGd4OjU4ZTE4M2MzMmU3ZWFlY2E) by a team from Unversity College, London.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for this. There are conflicting reports about it's effectiveness, some say it doesn't work, some say it works, I don't know what to believe. The reports you mentioned definitely helps my position that they work. So thanks.